# Can I store In-App Purchases on the Cloud(Parse)?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

Building an iOS App in Swift. Quick question about IAP's I want to implement. Currently, I have my In-App Purchases fixed in my app. Meaning, I would have to push an update to the app in order to change the visible information about the IAP, etc.

Does Apple allow me to store this In-App Purchase data in my cloud(Parse), or does it have to be local? Of course, the IAP's would have to be approved in iTunes Connect, but don't have to be used if they are approved.

My goal is to alternate through different plans without having to go through an entire app update.

I feel like the answer is a big obvious yes, but I just wanted to confirm before I begin coding it all in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you to decide where to store In-App Purchases.
Here is Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1) about storing in-app purchases data.

[How to store product identifiers:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW5)

> Every product you sell in your app has a unique product identifier.
> Your app uses these product identifiers to fetch information about
> products from the App Store, such as pricing, and to submit payment
> requests when users purchase those products. Your app can either read
> its list of product identifiers from a file in its app bundle or **fetch
> them from your server.**

[How to store associated content for purchased package:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW3)

> You can embed that content in your app’s bundle or you can **download it
> as needed** — each approach has its advantages and disadvantages.
> Embed smaller files (up to a few megabytes) in your app.
> Download larger files when needed.

Personally I want to say that all projects I was working on used remote server for getting in-app purchases data.
You don't need care about app approval in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to store In-App Purchases on the Cloud(Parse).

The in-app purchases for iOS are done through the Apple app store. We do not take a cut or interact with the transaction in any way. We simplify the process of setting up in app purchases, take care of interacting with the Apple server, perform receipt validation to ensure your purchases are done securely, take care of delivering the purchased content through PFFiles if you choose to use this mechanism and also provide an easy to use UI component for use in your app.

if you want to know in detail visit here http://blog.parse.com/announcements/in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that [using parse in swift(youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMdVZ592ZZE)

and [parse doc.](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#in-app-purchases)